# Linear Sorted Search

Tags: java, arrays, methods, linear-search

I have created this code which is a chart position. It should allow the user to enter a name already set in the array and the position of the artist will output whilst the input is not "end"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner (System.in);
    String names = null;

    String [] Artists = new String [];
    String [] Artists = new String []{"Fetty Wap", "Drake", "Miley Cyrus"
    ,"Kanye West","Chris Browna","Tinie Tempah","Robin Thicke","The Weeknd"
    ,"Jay Z","The Wanted"};

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter name ");
        names = kybd.next();
    } while (!names.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) ;
}

public static int linearSorted(int[] array, int item)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < array.length &&
    array[index] != item &&
    array[index] < item)
    {
        index++;
    }

    if (index == array.length ||
    array[index] > item)
    {
        index = -1;
    }
    return index;
}
}
```

The problem i have come to is that it does not show the chart position as it is sorted in the array

Comment: You do realize that half of your array is empty, since you just keep inserting different values into `Artists[1]` over and over?

Comment: It's cleaner to create fake data as `String[] s = new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"};`, so that the array is always compact and the correct size.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  You say you're trying to `allow the user to enter a name already set in the array and the position of the artist will output whilst the input is not "end"`, but you don't take an input for the position, nor do you ever call your `linearSorted` method.  Please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks for the suggestions they have been made. What i need the program to do is output the position of the name the user enters in order of the array for example, If the user enters "Miley Cyrus" the position should output as 3 as it is stored in position 3. I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: your array still has lots of empty elements. 
Artists[1] = "Chris Brown";
Artists[1] = "Tinie Tempah";
means to insert same element into that location so the last element you insert will be what is in that location. So not only do you have empty spaces, you are also losing data.

Comment: @FaforeTunde It has been changed

Comment: Okay. You also do not need to Arrays. One is okay. And what do you mean by linear sorted Array ? @CVirgo

Comment: @CVirgo does the answer below work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is a linear search to find the name index then this should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = null;
    String [] Artists = new String []{"Fetty Wap", "Drake", "Miley Cyrus"
            ,"Kanye West","Chris Browna","Tinie Tempah","Robin Thicke","The Weekend"
            ,"Jay Z","The Wanted"};

            do{
                System.out.print("Please enter name: ");
                name = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(linearSearch(Artists, name));
            } while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) ;

}

public static int linearSearch(String[] arr, String name){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].equals(name)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```